# How to complete the "ng test" process running in pipeline Jenkins

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins-pipeline, karma-runner

In pipeline Jenkins, I run tests of the application on Angular
with the command

```
ng test
```

I need that after they have been executed successfully, the process completes its work, and after that the current stage also completes and the next one starts.
But when I run this command, the process remains hanging indefinitely waiting for changes in the code.
I tried to run it with these parameters

```
ng test --wath=false --poll=500
```

If I run this command in the terminal, then everything is fine - the process ends and access to the command line appears.
But if I run it in pipeline Jenkins, it still keeps hanging.
What's the problem here?
How do I make it complete?